Why do we require $1 \wedge |x|^2$ to be integrable for Levy measures?
I will take the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity, in which case a Levy measure $\Pi$ is defined as a $\sigma$-finite measure such that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}} 1 \wedge |x|^2 \Pi(dx) < \infty.$$
Is there any reason why this condition is a part of the definition? Why is zero excluded from the domain?
Levy measures naturally arise in the Levy-Khintchine representation of Levy processes, and one other mathSE question said that this definition is so that the integral appearing in that representation is integrable but didn't give any details. I also have read this question but the answer/comments do not explain why this condition is needed.

The integrand in the Levy-Khintchine representation behaves like $x^{2}$ near $0$ and it is bounded outside a neighborhood of $0$.

@geetha290krm Thanks, so I guess this condition is just a technical one so that the integral converges?

The Levy -Kintchine formula is a great conquest of probability of the thirties. For understanding it, better is to assume that $\Pi$ is concentrated on $ (0,\infty)$ (thus using rather Laplace transform, a bit easier to manipulate) and to consider 3 cases:
A) Type zero: $\Pi$ is a bounded measure of mass $\lambda$: you probably know that then we get a so called compound Poisson, namely  the law of $$Y=X_1+\cdots+X_N$$ where $X_i\sim \Pi/\lambda$ and $N$ is Poisson of mean $\lambda$  with $N, X_1,\ldots, X_n,\ldots $independent. $$E(e^{-sY})=\exp(\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-sx}-1)\Pi(dx).$$
B) Type one: $\Pi$ is unbounded but $$\int_0^{\infty}\min (1,x)\Pi(dx)<\infty.$$
Then $E(e^{-sY})=\exp(\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-sx}-1)\Pi(dx).$ still holds. To understand $Y$, consider the bounded $\Pi_n,$ which is the restriction of $\Pi$ to $(1/n,\infty)$  and the corresponding $Y_n.$ Type 1 implies that $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ in law - just compute. Note that $Y\geq 0.$
C) Type two, the most difficult to understand.  We have $\int_0^{\infty}\min (1,x)\Pi(dx)=\infty$ but $$\int_0^{\infty}\min (1,x^2)\Pi(dx)<\infty.$$ Unfortunately $\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-sx}-1)\Pi(dx)$ diverges  and we have to add a compensatory term like $\tau(x)=\sin x$ or $x/(1+x^2)$ or else (depending of the authors) such that
$$\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-sx}-1-s\tau(x))\Pi(dx)$$ converges. With this choice $E(e^{-sY})$ does exist but behold! $Y$ is not positive. To see this, use again our good $Y_n$, which is not positive anymore because of $\tau$ (again, just compute). We have again $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ in law.

Thank you! Perhaps I have misunderstood, but your answer describes the consequences of these three cases. But why would we consider the type two case in the first place? Why is it a natural condition to impose?

If you impose only $\int_0^{\infty}\min (1,x^2)\Pi(dx)<\infty$  without $\int_0^{\infty}\min (1,x)\Pi(dx)=\infty$ then you are considering the three cases altogether in one shot. But as you surely notice, $\tau$ is useless  for types 0 and 1. If you keep it in types 0 and 1, you carry on a useless translation factor in the distribution of $Y.$

The condition $\int_0^{\infty}\min(1,x^2)\Pi(dx)<\infty$ is not only  a sufficient condition for having $Y$ infinitely divisible but also a necessary condition: this is the difficult part of the Levy Kintchine theorem. This is why it is 'natural.'

Thank you for your help!

Here's one (perhaps intuitive) way to think about the necessity of the condition $\int_{\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}}(1\wedge |x|^2)\,\Pi(dx)<\infty$.
Suppose $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a (one-dimensional) Lévy process with Lévy measure $\Pi$. The jumps $\{(t,X_t-X_{t-}): t>0\}$ form a Poisson point process in $(0,\infty)\times(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$ with intensity measure
$dt\otimes\Pi(dx)$.
The process $X$ is necessarily a semimartingale; as such the sum $\sum_{0<s\le t}(X_s-X_{s-})^2$ is a.s. finite for each $t>0$. From the well-known formula for the Laplace transform of a Poisson point process, this is equivalent to the condition that
$$
\int_{[0,\infty)\times(\Bbb R\setminus \{0\})}(1-\exp(-1_{[0,t]}(s)|x|^2)\,ds\,\Pi(dx)<\infty.
$$
This is in turn equivalent to
$$
\int_{\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}}(1-e^{-|x|^2})\,\Pi(dx)<\infty,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\int_{\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}}(1\wedge |x|^2)\,\Pi(dx)<\infty.
$$

Thank you, this indeed makes the condition appear more natural.
